# Compile and eval of base64 string

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64, eval

Here is some code I saw recently:

```
import base64

code="CmltcG9ydCBweW1vbmdvCmltcQ" #very long
eval(compile(base64.b64decode(code), "<string>", 'exec'))
```

I know what it does, it's very to decode it. But I got curious about how to do it by myself. So if I have an application and I want to encode it and make it run it by the code, what should  I do to encode it to get base64 string of it?

Comment: Just curious, what's the use case? The only one I can come up with, is some eastern egg.

Comment: @bereal: a misguided attempt at obfuscating the source code to prevent people from 'stealing' it or finding security holes in it, is the most common reason given for wanting to do this. Extremely ineffective and misguided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You encode valid python source code contained in a string:

```
import base64

source = '''\
print('Hello World!')
print('Not sure why you'd ever do this though..')
'''
code = base64.b64encode(source)
```

Comment: Also, source.encode('base64') would work (then don't have to import anything)

Comment: @bereal: Yup, just providing symmetry with the original.